# PHP PDO with bindParam vs bindValue?

Tags: php, pdo

**SOLUTION**

Change this:

```
foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field) {
    $value = isset($_POST[$field]) ? 1 : 0;
    $STH -> bindParam( ':' . $dbfield, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT, 1 );
}
```

to this:

```
foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field) {
    $value = isset($_POST[$field]) ? 1 : 0;
    $STH -> bindValue( ':' . $dbfield, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT );
}
```

---

**QUESTION**

I have the following code, which doesn't give any errors, but it doesn't do what I need it to do:

**PHP**

```
$fields = array(
    'db_col_1'  => 'cb_1',
    'db_col_2'  => 'cb_2',
    'db_col_3'  => 'cb_3'
);

$parts = array();

foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field){
    $parts[] = '`' . $dbfield . '` = :' . $dbfield;
}

$DBH = new PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db", "user", "pass" );
$DBH -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

//temp id
$id = 1;

$STH = $DBH -> prepare( 'UPDATE `table1` SET ' . join(', ', $parts) . ' WHERE `id`= :id' );

$STH -> bindParam( ':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT, 10 );

foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field) {
    $value = isset($_POST[$field]) ? 1 : 0;
    $STH -> bindParam( ':' . $dbfield, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT, 1 );
}

$STH -> execute();
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="cb_1" name="cb_1" type="checkbox" value="cb_1" />
<br />
<input id="cb_2" name="cb_2" type="checkbox" value="cb_2" />
<br />
<input id="cb_3" name="cb_3" type="checkbox" value="cb_3" />
```

The database goes get updated, but if I check the checkboxes as follows:

**SAMPLE CHECKBOX STATES**

```
cb_1 = 1
cb_2 = 1
cb_3 = 0
```

Every column in the db gets `0`.

If I check the checkboxes as follows:

**SAMPLE CHECKBOX STATES**

```
cb_1 = 0
cb_2 = 0
cb_3 = 1
```

Every column in the db gets `1`.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Could it be because `bindParam` binds the actual variable `$value` (by reference) which I think, by the time the loop ends, has a value based on `$_POST['cb_3']`?

So I think I am supposed to be using `bindValue`? But not sure how..  I've checked the documentation, but find it confusing.

Comment: A [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) contains an advise on this very matter

Comment: I think you should have tried `bindValue()` before asking here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[PDOStatement::bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) is a way to tell PDO: «when you execute this statement later, please read the value from this variable». That means that when you call `$STH -> execute()` the `$value` must exist and must keep the intended value.

Since you are using it this way:

```
foreach($fields as $dbfield => $field) {
    $value = isset($_POST[$field]) ? 1 : 0;
    $STH -> bindParam( ':' . $dbfield, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT, 1 );
}
```

... `$value` gets overwritten on each loop iteration and your values get lost. (Only the last one remains.)

You need to use [PDOStatement::bindValue()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) that means: «store this value and use it later when you execute the statement». This way, the variable is no longer necessary.

Comment: I say down with the hit-and-run downvoting :/ Thanks for the explanation.