# PDO bindParam - last value inserted in all

Tags: php, pdo

I have this code for inserting in DB:

```
    public function insert($table,$parameters=array()){
    $param="";
    $val=array();
    $insert= str_replace(':', '', array_keys($parameters)); //remove :
    //Build Query
    $query="INSERT INTO {$this->dbinfo["prefix"]}$table";
    if(is_array($insert)){

        $query.=' (`'.implode("`,`",$insert).'`) VALUES (:'.implode(', :',$insert).')';

        $result = $this->db->prepare($query);

        foreach($parameters as $key=>$param) {
          $result->bindParam($key, $param);
        }
    }

    $result->execute();
    if($err=$this->error_message($this->db->errorInfo())) {
        $this->query=strtr($query,$parameters);
        $this->db_error=$err;
        exit;
    }
    ++$this->num_queries;
    $last_id = FALSE;
    $last_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
return $last_id;        
}
```

Error handling:

```
private function error_message($error){
    if(!empty($error[2])){
        return $error[2];
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

The call sample can look like:

```
$this->db->insert("log_url",array(":name"=>"url",":urlid"=>15,":type"=>0));
```

The example above insert in the database row filled with the last value, in this case 0. When I delete the type, it fill all with 15. Etc...
Somewhere in insert function is mistake, but i cannot find it.

Any information helps. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1179874/1233508

Comment: Are you binding the query?

Comment: @DCoder I'm not sure if I understand well. Bindvalue must be used in this case? In case security is it equivalent (Is only changing ok)?

Comment: @Hudixt I want to do correct insert to the database and insert the data from the function. But the issue is, the last data is defined for all in cycle.

Comment: Yes, you need to use `bindValue` in this case. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/15154328/1233508 for another good explanation.

Comment: @DCoder Thank you for good notice, but i think there is bigger issue. Changing to bindValue result no insert to the DB.

Comment: `implode($insert,"`,`")` should be `implode("`,`", $insert)`. You have made this mistake twice.

Comment: Your error handling code is useless, because you `exit` without logging or displaying any helpful error messages. Change it so you can see the built query, the parameters being bound, and the error message the database gives you.

Comment: @DCoder I update me question with improved error and error function. Still no success. Maybe is the insert function still buggy.

Comment: `$result->execute();` missing, now solved

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answered:

Missing execute

```
$result->execute();
```